# Extract IDs from Text in many columns

Tags: r, dplyr, extract, tidyr, separator

I have a huge df which is separated by different symbols (#,space,,).
After reading the data I have columns which aren't separated yet. 
I tried to use `tidyr::separate` to separate the columns. 
But as I have many columns the result of the separation overwrites the next column.

I tried to use ''tidyr::separate'' to separate the columns. 
But as I have many columns the result of the separation overwrites the next column.

the content of one column looks like this:

`Markt#ID=3002349#X=8612088#Y=50228881#RI=1|&RD=10062019&RT=6:46&L=1543&SM=0#1#2&CT=-1#-1#-1#-1#-1&P1=1111111111111111&O1=99999999&T1=99999999&F=-1&RF=1999991999999999111090999999&GP=FF=cost=-1|minDist=0|maxDist=2000|speed=100|routingType=1|ellipseRadius=1000|maxDur=120|waitTime=-1|linDistRouting=0|#BF=cost=-1|minDist=0|maxDist=2000|speed=100|routingType=1|ellipseRadius=1000|maxDur=120|waitTime=-1|linDistRouting=0|#&`

All in all I have 12 columns from which I want to extract the `IDs` and the `coordinates`.

Expected results:

```
 ID       X         Y
 3002349  8612088  50228881
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the rows have the same format you can use `tidyr::extract`

```
tidyr::extract(df, v1, c("ID", "X", "Y"), regex = ".*ID=(\\d+)#X=(\\d+)#Y=(\\d+)")
#       ID       X        Y
#1 3002349 8612088 50228881
```

This extracts numbers which are followed by `ID`, `X` and `Y` labels from the text.

**data**

```
x <- "Markt#ID=3002349#X=8612088#Y=50228881#RI=1|&RD=10062019&RT=6:46&L=1543&SM=0#1#2&CT=-1#-1#-1#-1#-1&P1=1111111111111111&O1=99999999&T1=99999999&F=-1&RF=1999991999999999111090999999&GP=FF=cost=-1|minDist=0|maxDist=2000|speed=100|routingType=1|ellipseRadius=1000|maxDur=120|waitTime=-1|linDistRouting=0|#BF=cost=-1|minDist=0|maxDist=2000|speed=100|routingType=1|ellipseRadius=1000|maxDur=120|waitTime=-1|linDistRouting=0|#&"
df <- data.frame(v1 = x)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in `base R` using `read.csv` and `sub`

```
read.csv(text= sub(".*ID=(\\d+)#X=(\\d+)#Y=(\\d+).*", "\\1,\\2,\\3", 
           df$v1), header = FALSE, col.names = c("ID", "X", "Y"))
#     ID       X        Y
#1 3002349 8612088 50228881
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(v1 = structure(1L, .Label = "Markt#ID=3002349#X=8612088#Y=50228881#RI=1|&RD=10062019&RT=6:46&L=1543&SM=0#1#2&CT=-1#-1#-1#-1#-1&P1=1111111111111111&O1=99999999&T1=99999999&F=-1&RF=1999991999999999111090999999&GP=FF=cost=-1|minDist=0|maxDist=2000|speed=100|routingType=1|ellipseRadius=1000|maxDur=120|waitTime=-1|linDistRouting=0|#BF=cost=-1|minDist=0|maxDist=2000|speed=100|routingType=1|ellipseRadius=1000|maxDur=120|waitTime=-1|linDistRouting=0|#&", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```